# bootstrap four box layout with margin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want bootstrap reponsive layout with four center aligned box with image and text in each. Refer to the attached image

I tried the following but the boxes do not have space in between and its not showing properly.

```
<div class="row  justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-4 colMenu">
                             <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
                            <img src="./assets/img/sample.png"
class="menuImg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 colMenu ">
                                <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
                               <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
                           </div>

                        <div class="w-100"></div>

                        <div class="col-4 colMenu ">
                        <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
                        <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-4 colMenu">
                                <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
                               <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
                           </div>
                      </div>



.colMenu{
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-color: #000000;
  }

  .menuImg{
    height: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: change the class col-4 for col-3

Comment: If you want only two boxes on each row you should use two rows and only two cols in each row.

Comment: Sorry, I was not familiar with the features of the very new bootstrap 4. Seems to be a legit way of doing it as you have done. Though, I don't know if it is possible (or at least feasable) to introduce padding in between the rows/columns of bootstrap. You might be better off by adding a box inside each `col` element and setting border/outline and margins on those...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin each box, since border ignores padding.

```
.colMenu {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what space you required, between the boxes? If yes then you need apply `calc()` function to achieve it for `col-4` I supposed to you used Bootstrap latest version:

```
.colMenu{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  width: calc(33.333333% - 30px); /* 30px of combined 2 side margin 15+15 = 30
  margin:15px; /* Applied margin */
}
```

But keep it mind for responsive view you should modify accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
 .colMenu{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-color: #000000;
 width: calc(33.333333% - 30px);
 margin:15px;
 }
 
 .menuImg{
 height: 40%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row  justify-content-center">
<div class="col-4 colMenu">
     <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
class="menuImg">
</div>
<div class="col-4 colMenu ">
        <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="menuImg">
   </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

<div class="col-4 colMenu ">
<h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="menuImg">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4 colMenu">
        <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="menuImg">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

What are you trying to do here? Do you want your code to do what you show in your image?

First I think you are wrong trying to mix bootstrap and hardcoded css rules. And
what is `<div class="w-100"></div>` for?

Do you want 2x2 blocks or 4 blocks display inline?

For the first case you'll need this code :

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 colMenu">
           <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
           <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 colMenu">
            <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
            <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 colMenu">
            <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
            <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-6 colMenu">
            <h3 >SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
            <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
       </div>
 </div>
```

For the second case you'll need to replace col-md-6 by col-md-3 like so :

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 colMenu">
           <h3>SAMPLE TEXT</h3>
           <img src="./assets/img/sample.png" class="menuImg">
       </div>
...
```

Now if you want it to be centered and smaller, you'll need to play with offset and reduce the size. For the first example you'll have a `<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">` and a `<div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">` or something like this ;)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes

Comment: The `class="w-100"` is from the new Bootstrap 4 grid system. Check out this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width